# Java stream modifying strings

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to ask you guys for help in modyfing my list of strings using fp. Im new to stream api, have some basic knowledge but can't resolve this task. I have three list of strings, each of them contain title of movie in my origin language and translation in English, then every list of strings go to map. I want to reach the outcome that I print movies from list separated with '>' and then when it switches to another list I want to place '|'. For example:
Zelazny czlowiek>IronMan|Msciciele>Avengers|Blyskawica>Flash

```
   public Map<String, List<String>> getMovies() {
    List<String> ironManTranslations = new ArrayList<>();
    ironManTranslations.add("Żelazny Człowiek");
    ironManTranslations.add("Iron Man");

    List<String> avengersTranslations = new ArrayList<>();
    avengersTranslations.add("Mściciele");
    avengersTranslations.add("Avengers");

    List<String> flashTranslations = new ArrayList<>();
    flashTranslations.add("Błyskawica");
    flashTranslations.add("Flash");

    Map<String, List<String>> booksTitlesWithTranslations = new HashMap<>();
    booksTitlesWithTranslations.put("IM", ironManTranslations);
    booksTitlesWithTranslations.put("AV", avengersTranslations);
    booksTitlesWithTranslations.put("FL", flashTranslations);

    return booksTitlesWithTranslations;
}

public void printMovies(){

    getMovies().values().stream().flatMap(movie -> movie.stream().map(s -> s + ">")).forEach(System.out::print);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` operator to create a translation pair for each list. And then use `joining` collector to join them between the lists using the | operator. Here's how it looks.

```
String mStr = booksTitlesWithTranslations.values().stream()
    .map(l -> l.get(0) + ">" + l.get(1))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

Comment: Seems to be easy now. Thank you so much for your help, for sure I'll remember this for future tasks like this one.

Comment: The general solution for arbitrary list sizes instead of fixed two, is `.map(l -> String.join(">", l))`

Comment: I didn't even know that. Thanks for letting us know.